# Why is my answer not correct?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

You are watering a garden. The height $h$ (in feet) of water spraying from the garden hose can be modeled by $h(x)=−0.1x^2+0.7x+3$, where $x$ is the horizontal distance (in feet) from where you are standing. You raise the hose so that the water hits the ground $1$ foot farther from where you are standing. Write a function that models the new path of the water.
We can move the curve to the right: $x\mapsto x-1$ and get $-0.1 x^2+0.9 x+2.2$, but the solution to the problem says the correct answer is $−0.1x^2 +0.7x+4.4$, which seems to say you should move the curve up such that the root moves to the right by $1$ foot.  Can someone explain why this is the correct answer?

Comment: For your $-0.1 x^2+0.9 x+2.2$ answer, you are going to need going to need to change the angle of water leaving the hose (the derivative at $x=0$) and the speed at which the water leaves the hose (the water needs to gain additional height to get to the same maximum since it starts lower).  For the $−0.1x^2 +0.7x+4.4$ answer, you just change the initial height of the hose - as in the question - and can keep the leaving  angle and speed the same.

Comment: That makes sense.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For your $-0.1 x^2+0.9 x+2.2$ answer (the horizontal translation in red below), you are going to need going to need to change the angle of water leaving the hose (the derivative at $x=0$) and the speed at which the water leaves the hose (the water needs to gain additional height and potential energy to get to the same maximum height since it starts lower).

For the $−0.1x^2 +0.7x+4.4$ answer (the vertical translation in blue below), you just change the initial height of the hose - as in the question - and can keep the leaving  angle and speed the same.

Here is a graph, with the original trajectory in black:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The question specifies that you **raise** the hose. This implies a vertical dilation or translation.

Of course, there are multiple transformations which achieve the required result, but in the *context* of the problem I believe the writer of the problem was after a vertical translation.

In a related matter - I have an issue with the absence of a domain for the function. Was there a domain specified originally?